# How to draw circular segment using paper.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, paperjs

How to draw circular segment using [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/)

I want to draw the circular segments as shown in the image. Each segment is independent and will later be used for interactive purposes.

[image]

I tried something like

```
//Temporary background circle
var keys = new Path.Circle(view.center, 130);
keys.fillColor = '#F1F1F1';

var home = new Path.Circle(view.center, 50);
home.fillColor = '#ee2a33';

var start = new Point(view.center.x, view.center.y-130);
var through = new Point(view.center.x-125, view.center.y-40);
var to = new Point(view.center.x-130, view.center.y);

var path = new Path.Arc(start, through, to);
path.strokeColor = 'black';
path.fillColor = 'green';
```

And it renders something like below

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After several attempts, I came up with this. If anyone needs the same thing for whatever reason, maybe this will help.

```
//Creating keys
var arcOne = createSegment('#f1f1f1');
var arcTwo = createSegment('#666666');
var arcThree = createSegment('#333333');
var arcFour = createSegment('#666666');
var arcFive = createSegment('#999999');
var arcSix = createSegment('#000000');

arcTwo.rotate(-60, view.center);
arcThree.rotate(-120, view.center);
arcFour.rotate(60, view.center);
arcFive.rotate(120, view.center);
arcSix.rotate(180, view.center);


//center white
var center = new Path.Circle(view.center, 50);
center.fillColor = '#F1F1F1';

//Create Each segment
function createSegment(fillcolor){
    //Segment One
    var start = new Point(view.center.x, view.center.y-130);
    var through = new Point(view.center.x-90, view.center.y-94);
    var to = new Point(view.center.x-113, view.center.y-64);
    var name = Path.Arc(start, through, to);

    name.add(new Point(view.center.x, view.center.y));
    name.add(new Point(view.center.x, view.center.y-130));
    name.fillColor = fillcolor;
    return name;
}
```

Comment: I think `name.add(new Point(view.center.x, view.center.y-130));` should actually be `name.closed = true;` , else there is a small disconnect in the end of the stroke.

Comment: this answer is excellent ! it's better to explain how to come up with those values though.